# Android google maps clustering custom pins

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I recently implemented clustering in my Android app, and I have managed to set a dynamic image for each marker with Picasso. However, not all markers have an image, and those that do not have it must be displayed with a custom marker my designer has provided.

This is the custom renderer I use:

```
private class CustomRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyMarker>{

    private IconGenerator iconGenerator;
    private ImageView imageView;

    CustomRenderer() {
        super(ShopsMapActivity.this, map, clusterManager);
        iconGenerator = new IconGenerator(ShopsMapActivity.this);

        imageView = new ImageView(ShopsMapActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(PIN_SIZE, PIN_SIZE));
        int padding = Global.getXPercentOfWidth(1f);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        iconGenerator.setContentView(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyMarker item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        if(item.hasLogo()) {
            // this part works perfectly
            loadAsync(imageView, item.getLogo());
            try {
                Bitmap icon = iconGenerator.makeIcon();
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
                icon.recycle();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else {
         // this is the part that does not work. It should display a custom pin, but instead it displays a small empty white marker that should hold an image from Picasso. Problem is that there is no image for Picasso to download            
         markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDefaultIconBitmap()));
        }
    }

    private void loadAsync(final ImageView imageView, final String url) {
        Picasso.with(ShopsMapActivity.this)
                .load(url)
                .into(imageView);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is createDefaultIconBitmap()?

Comment: it gets a drawable from resources, rescales it and returns the bitmap

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252022/android-how-to-reload-custom-markers-once-the-image-is-downloaded-via-picasso