# Download image with glide from network then show clustering map google utils

Tags: java, android

If I use local resource then everything is ok. But if I try to load image from network, somehow it does not work
My problem is exactly the same as this problem:
[Android : how to reload custom markers once the image is downloaded via Picasso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252022/android-how-to-reload-custom-markers-once-the-image-is-downloaded-via-picasso)

As you can see, Kali Aney tried to load image into mImageView (onBeforeClusterItemRendered)

However Stas Parshin's answer had nothing to do with mImageView. I have tried and it does not work

Comment: can you please list you code for load image from network. So I can help you easily. and list what you are trying to do with glide or Picasso.

Comment: My problem is exactly this one and you can see Stas Parshin's answer with glide but I notice that this code is nothing to do with 
 mImageView: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252022/android-how-to-reload-custom-markers-once-the-image-is-downloaded-via-picasso